# "Content-Disposition: attachment" via SQL Server mailing possible?

Tags: sql-server, email-attachments, mailing

We have the request, that an attachment, which was sent by SQL Server Mail is missing the definition `Content-Disposition: attachment` if there's an attachment sent with the mail.

In the source code of the mail you can see that the mail arrives correctly with the `Content-Type: multipart/mixed`, but the XML attachment (before the binary data) is only labelled with the following tag:
`Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=106131.xml`
However, in order for the attachment to be recognised during the check, the multipart attachment must be marked as an attachment with
`Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Is there a way to change this in SQL Server Management Studio in the mailing configuration so that the tag `Content-Disposition: attachment` is sent in this form?

Another customer has SQL Server 2019 and isn't facing these problems.
Customer with this problems has SQL Server 2014.
Has this been changed in the past?

Thanks for your kind responses in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a proper mail system, SQL Server is not intended as a generalized mail system, only for database alerts. Why are they on SQL Server 2014 anyway, if it's out of support?

Comment: Why do you really need the header, I'm pretty sure people could send attachments without issues in db mail even in sql server 2014

Comment: We need this header because this is a request from XRechnung.  XRechnung is a standard for the type and technical composition of invoice information in an XML data set. As we have always used SQL Server Mail for our mail dispatch and have not yet had any problems, we have not yet considered using a different mail client.